# Was Gradle syntax frozen with version 1.0?

Tags: java, build, gradle

I remember issue then I could not perform build with old version 0.7 of Gradle when my colleague was using 0.8...

So was Gradle syntax frozen with version 1.0?

I didn't find such statement in [release note](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes)...

Comment: I think this question is better asked on the [Gradle Forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle) where you can make sure that the Gradleware engineers will read it. IMHO I think there will be changes to the DSL in the future no matter what. Just not as frequent as pre-1.0-final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1.x series will see major new features (for example parallel build execution) while at the same time retaining backwards compatibility with 1.0. Once we make the jump to 2.x (which we don't plan to do anytime soon), certain 1.x versions will still be supported for an extended period of time (long-term support model).

Comment: May you point to official statement about backwards compatibility in 1.x series at http://www.gradle.org/ ??

Comment: I think an official statement is forthcoming.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I wanted to ask about this at mail list, but SO is easy place to do this...

Answer (score 1):

It has no evidence. I didn't see any information about frozen api